# Explanation of pilot jobs in distributed/grid computing

Tags: distributed-systems, scheduling

I'm reading into **grid systems**/**distributed systems** and came across *pilot jobs* that I can't find a decent explanation for. The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilot_job) is not understandable to me.

I know multi-level schemes from distributed graph algorithms, and I guess in this context it means first the resources are scheduled to the applications and then the application does internal scheduling? But some more explanation would be appreciated. In my application the pilot jobs are empty jobs that are sent to resources, acquire them and then demand jobs from a (central?) job queue in a pulling strategy (as far as I understood it).

I think it would be very helpful if somebody could point out an alternative scheduling strategy and compare its pros and cons to those of the pilot job variant.

Comment: So where did you get stuck at pilot jobs? You are asking about rewording the Wikipedia and some comparison of methods? What is your application? Could you clarify single objective (some additional question is ok as long it is so connected to current question that there is no point of making it standalone, otherwise we discourage multiple questions per post). I am not sure if asking for methods comparison is proper, but we shall see.

Comment: I didn't really find a comprehensive explanation, so not much getting stuck.
The basic scenario, as I understand it, is that you have _N_ resources and _M_ jobs with varying length and requirements etc which become available at different times and then you try to schedule them in an 'optimized' way. Now I don't see how giving each resource an empty job makes the scheduling easier? How did that change the problem, the _N_ pilot jobs (really N?) still have to choose jobs from the global job queue.